# Acyclic graph in Django

Tags: django, graph, directed-acyclic-graphs, django-mptt

I would like to achieve acyclic graph structure in Django. For example I have some categories in tree structure:

```
Guitars
- Classical Guitars
- Western Guitars
- Guitars for Children

Ukuleles
- Soprano Ukulele
- Concert Ukulele
- Baryton Ukulele
- Ukuleles for Children
```

Now I would like to add category `For Children` and create link to existing categories `Guitars for Children` and `Ukuleles for Children`. But I have to avoid cycles in this graph.

What is the easiest way to achieve it? Is possible to use `django-mptt`? I need it dynamic and easy modifiable in administration. You can image it like categories structure in complex eshop.

Comment: Can you not just use a `BooleanField` field `for_children` ?

Comment: It's just an example. I need it dynamic.

Comment: I know how to make a relationship between models. But I don't know, how to avoid cycles in this graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [django-dag](https://github.com/elpaso/django-dag). I don't have much experience with it, but it could fit.